# Loop doesn't give an output

Tags: conditionals

The following conditional is not working; when I use \def\Assignment{Examples}, the file  \input{\code/Assessment/#1/#2/#2} is not read.

```
  \ifx\Assignment Examples
 \qformat{\underline{\textbf{#5 \thequestion } }}
         \loop      
\input{\code/Assessment/#1/#2/#2}
    \addtocounter{int}{1}\ifnum\value{int}<#4  \repeat
  \else
    \if\Assignment Quiz
  \scriptsize{\textbf{This assessment instrument assesses the following Course Learning Outcomes (CLO) and grading scheme: }} \vspace{-0.25em}
\qformat{\underline{\textbf{#5 \thequestion } }\droptotalpoints}
        \loop      
 \input{\code/Assessment/#1/#2/CLO}
\input{\code/Assessment/#1/#2/#2}
    \addtocounter{int}{1}\ifnum\value{int}<#4  \repeat
  \fi
\fi

 } \rmfamily}{\medskip}
```

Comment: no it didn't answer my question

Comment: Maybe I should have put it as normal comment instead of a duplicate comment - however it shows that `\ifx\Assignment Examples` will fail because it compares the token `\Assignment` to the token `E`. Also later on `\if\Assignment Quiz` does not have the `x` in `\ifx` and if it would it would fail for the same reason (comparing `\Assignment` to `Q`).

Comment: `\ifx\Assignment E` is always false as `\Assignment` is not `E` also ` \scriptsize{`  makes the rest of the document script size, latex size commands do not take an argument.

Comment: also you can not nest `\loop` macros.

Comment: based on your suggestion I added the following \def\Examples{Examples}
\def\Quiz{Quiz} and I adjusted the code to  \ifx\Assignment \Examples, but still I didn't get any output